# Output "from Now" string in Kotlin using UTC timezone

Tags: android, kotlin, timezone, momentjs, prettytime

I'm trying to write a Kotlin function which replicates the behaviour of `fromNow` in the `moment` library.

I have the following code:

```
fun formatDuration(dateTime: String): String {
    try {
        val parsedDateTime = Instant.parse(dateTime)
        val prettyTime = PrettyTime()
        prettyTime.reference = Instant.now().atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).toInstant()
        return prettyTime.format(parsedDateTime)
    } catch (e: DateTimeParseException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        return "Invalid date/time format"
    }
}
```

The problem is when the device time is `9:44` and the input string is `2023-02-19T11:48:09.958Z`, and the current `UTC` time is `15:19` it will output `2 hours from now`, even though it should output `3 hours ago` like the `moment` function does as the timestamp is in UTC.

How can I fix this to always take into account UTC time not local time when calculating the difference?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to change:

from:

```
val parsedDateTime = Instant.parse(dateTime)
```

to:

```
val parsedDateTime = Instant.parse(dateTime).atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).toInstant()
```

Comment: doesn't work for me